# Highcharts - bubble chart labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a JS project in which i am using highcharts (bubble chart). It looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, I have two plot lines (label 1 and label 2). What i want to do is to have a plot line for each sector of my chart (meaning 4 of them). Is that possible to implement such thing? I was only able to add plot lines in the top sectors so far. Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.name}, fat: {point.x}g, sugar: {point.y}g, obesity: {point.z}%.'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Изменение'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        plotLines: [
            {
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 65,
            label: {
                    align: "left",
                rotation: 0,
                y: 15,
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic',
                    color: "#418744"
                },
                text: 'label 1'
            },
            zIndex: 3
            },
        ],
    },
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Ускорение'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        plotLines: [
            {
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 75,
            label: {
                align: 'left',
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic',
                    color: "#4B514C"
                },
                text: 'label 2',
                x: 0
            },
            zIndex: 3
            }
        ],
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        followPointer: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            { x: 80, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' },
            { x: 50, y: 55.9, z: 14.7, name: 'RU', country: 'Russia' },
        ],
        colorByPoint: true
    }]
});
```

P.S. my full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8wbftnx1/82/)

Comment: I would suggest , there are event listener in charts on render where you will get reference to canvas and also coordinates of datapoint in said canvas and using that canvas you can draw line in canvas

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement such behaviour by using X and Y props:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.name}, fat: {point.x}g, sugar: {point.y}g, obesity: {point.z}%.'
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
       /*  title: {
            text: 'Изменение',
        }, */
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        plotLines: [
            {
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 0,
            label: {
                    align: "left",
                rotation: 0,
                y: -5,
                x: 20,
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic',
                    color: "#418744",
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                },
                text: 'Ускоряющийся рост'
            },
            zIndex: 3
            },
          {
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 0,
            label: {
                    align: "right",
                rotation: 0,
                y: -5,
                x: -20,
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic',
                    color: "#4B514C",
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                },
                text: 'Ускорение после спада'
            },
            zIndex: 3
            },
          {
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 0,
            label: {
                    align: "left",
                rotation: 0,
                y: 350,
                x: 20,
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic',
                    color: "#4B514C",
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                },
                text: 'Замедляющийся рост'
            },
            zIndex: 3
            },
          {
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 0,
            label: {
                    align: "right",
                rotation: 0,
                y: 350,
                x: -20,
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic',
                    color: "#D21717",
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                },
                text: 'Развивающееся замедление'
            },
            zIndex: 3
            },
        ],
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Ускорение'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        plotLines: [
            {
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 0,
            zIndex: 3
            }
        ],
    },

    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        followPointer: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            { x: 13, y: 10, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' },
            { x: -5, y: -7, z: 14.7, name: 'RU', country: 'Russia' },
            { x: -12, y: 3, z: 14.7, name: 'EN', country: 'England' },
        ],
        colorByPoint: true
    }]

});
```

[image]
Full code just in case: https://jsfiddle.net/8wbftnx1/232/